# $(A \times B)^c = (A^c \times Y) \cup (X \times B^c)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be universal sets and $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$.

Then, I want to prove that $(A \times B)^c=(A^c \times Y) \cup (X \times B^c)$.

I think that i have to suppose that $(x,y) \in (A \times B)^c$, then $(x,y) \in (X \times Y) \setminus (A\times B) \Rightarrow (x,y) \in (A^c \times Y) \cup (X \times B^c)$, but is this correct? And how should I prove that?

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y)\in(A\times B)^c$. Then $(x,y)\not\in A\times B$ which implies that $x\not\in A$ or $y\not\in B$. Hence, $(x,y)\in A^c\times Y$ or $(x,y)\in X\times B^c$.

For the other direction. Let $(x,y)\in (A^c \times Y) \cup (X \times B^c)$. This implies that $(x,y)\in A^c \times Y$ or $(x,y)\in X \times B^c$, namely $x\not\in A$ or $y\not\in B$. Thus, $(x,y)\not\in A\times B$.

To see this result and get some intuition check for example: $A=B=[0,1]$ and $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)